# TableView setEditing also enables row deletion

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I want to reorder the rows in my tableview. I have already implemented these two methods.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath{
    NSLog(@"Move Row At IndexPath");
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSLog(@"Can Move Row At IndexPath");
    if(indexPath.section == 0 || (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0)){
        NSLog(@"Don't Move");
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;

}
```

Now i only want to reorder the cells and don't want user to delete the cells. But when i enable editing `[tableView setEditing:yes animated:YES];` then it also lets user to delete the items from the table view i only want to show the reorder control in the table view, like the one on iphone Settings-> Notification Center and then press edit.

Can some have an idea how  to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try Implementing this way**

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    return YES;
}

// method to remove "-" sign from editing mode
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}

-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    return NO;
}

-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    return YES;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath 
{
    // Update your datasource here and work accordingly......>
}
```

Comment: You don't need the first 3 methods to implement moving rows... These methods are for insertion and deletion only.

Answer (score 0):

Implement [tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006941-CH3-SW26) and return `NO` to it. By default all rows are editable.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To re-order the cells you should use the method `tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath:` editing is only for insertion and deletion. More information [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/showsReorderControl).

Answer (score 0):

After using this:

```
[tableView setEditing:yes animated:YES];
```

Use below:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath {

}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}
```